# Request doesn't work with URL from Response Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Request doesn't work with the URL i get from response body. The URL prints fine in the console but working with it just doesn't work

```
request.post(`https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/csv_export?app_id=${constants.ONESIGNAL_APPID}`, {
    json: {
        "extra_fields": ["country"]
    }, headers: constants.AUTH_HEADER
}, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
    }
    
    console.log(body)

    var csvURL = body.csv_file_url
    console.log(csvURL)

    request(csvURL) // <--- Request doesn't work with the csvURL from body
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./ji.csv.gz", { encoding: 'binary'}))
```

This just doesn't work! If i put the exact same printed URL string and put inside the request URL it works somehow, but if I take it from the response body directly it doesn't work.

This is the body output:

```
{
    csv_file_url: 'https://onesignal.s3.amazonaws.com/csv_exports/theappid.csv.gz'
}
```

I also tried using axios instead of request but it still doesn't work

**Update: Using node-fetch doesn't work either**

````
async function getAllCountries() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(`https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/csv_export?app_id=${constants.ONESIGNAL_APPID}`, {
        method: 'post',
        body:    JSON.stringify({ extra_fields: ["country"] }),
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ****', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        const csvURL = json.csv_file_url
        
        console.log(csvURL)
        
        fetch(csvURL)
        .then(
            res => {
                const dest = fs.createWriteStream("./ji.csv.gz");
                res.body.pipe(dest);
                res.body.on("end", () => {
                    gunzip('ji.csv.gz', 'ji.csv', async () => {
                        
                        const usersCSVJSON = await csv().fromFile("ji.csv");
                        const onlyCountriesArray = usersCSVJSON.map((value) => { return value.country })
                        const singleCountries = new Set(onlyCountriesArray)
                        resolve([...singleCountries])
                    })
                });
                dest.on('error', (error)=> {
                    console("ERRORR")
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the url directly the file hasn't been created yet on the server so it didn't work. I needed to delay the function so now it works

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need any special library, like Request or Axios, to do AJAX.  All you need is the (built-in) `fetch` method (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for more info).

(**NOTE:** On Node you will need a library, eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch, since it sadly has no built-in fetch. But by using such a library you can then `fetch` the exact same way on both your client and server ... without a client library.)

Second ...

> If i put the exact same printed URL string and put inside the request URL it works somehow, but if I take it from the response body directly it doesn't work.

This suggests that there is something in the response body you're not seeing.  For instance, there might be a newline character, or some other special/invisible text character, at the start of the URL.  If so, that could explain your problem.

To debug, I would recommend logging them side-by-side:

```
console.log(csvURL, '*PRINTED URL*')
```

to see if you can observe any difference.

Also you could try checking the `.length` of both strings, or doing a `csvUrl.trim()` to see if that helps.  Ultimately though, your results are telling you that the two strings *aren't* the same ... because if they were, then your results would be also.

Comment: It is the exact same URL... I just don't understand it. The request gives me the body output above but it doesn't look like a json. If i use Postman i get it in JSON format..

Comment: No it hasn't something todo with the json thing. I have no idea really... Even taking that URL converting it to a complete new JSON object and retrieve it again doesn't work for the request...

Comment: So first off, I went to look into this library and found "As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated".  Really, you should be using `fetch`, or at the very least a supported library like Axios.

Comment: But second, what you're explaining makes no sense.  If your endpoint is returning JSON, then you're getting back *at least* `{url: 'some url'}` ... but you *can't* fetch/request/axios an object (or a string of one).  You first have to *parse* that JSON into an object, then get a *property* of the object.  But from your code it looks like `body` is already an object, because you're doing `body.csv_file_url`?

Comment: Also I notice your code does `json: {"extra_fields": ["country"]}` ... but when I look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/request I see no use of a `json` property like that; the closest I see is a single `json:true`.  I think you're confused about how to use this library, but rather than learn a deprecated library you really want to switch to `fetch` (or, again, *at least* Axios)

Comment: See my updates question. Even using node-fetch doesn't resolve my issue.


I get back the body I posted above and the library makes it to an object automatically so i can work with it because accessing `body.csv_file_url` wouldn't work without that step obviously

Comment: You're using it wrong.  Please review the link I provided on how to use it properly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch  The  very first code example on that page shows you *exactly* how to use `fetch` properly.

Comment: When using the url directly the file hasn't been created yet on the server so it didn't work. I needed to delay the function so now it works. As i said it has nothing todo with the library